# Android: How to use getChildFragmentManager() in an ArrayAdapter class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

How can i use the method `getChildFragmentManager()` in a custom adapter that extends `ArrayAdapter<>` ?

Here's my code if you need to see it:

MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Content> {


    Context context;
    List<Content> myList;
    public static final String pattern = "(?<=watch\\?v=|/videos/|embed\\/)[^#\\&\\?]*";
    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Content> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.myList = objects;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (myList != null)
            return myList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Content getItem(int position) {
        if (myList != null)
            return myList.get(position);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        if (myList != null)
            return myList.get(position).hashCode();
        return 0;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Holder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new Holder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            holder.contId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.content_id);
            holder.contType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.txtTeaser = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teaser);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover_photo);
            holder.youTubeVideo = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.youTube_frame);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

        }


        Content content = getItem(position);

        holder.contId.setText(content.getId());
        holder.contType.setText(content.getType());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(content.getTitle());
        holder.txtTeaser.setText(content.getTeaser());
        Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(content.getImageUrl())).into(holder.imageView);

        if(content.getCoverVideo() != null && !content.getCoverVideo().equals("")){
            String cover_video = content.getCoverVideo();
            Pattern compiledPattern = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = compiledPattern.matcher(cover_video);
            if(matcher.find()){
                cover_video =  matcher.group();
            }
            Bundle youTubeBundle = new Bundle();
            youTubeBundle.putString("link", cover_video);

            FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager(); // <------ Can't resolve method

            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

            ArticleYouTubeFragment youtubeFragment = new ArticleYouTubeFragment();
            youtubeFragment.setArguments(youTubeBundle);
            transaction.replace(R.id.list_youTube_frame, youtubeFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class Holder {

        TextView contId;
        TextView contType;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtTeaser;
        ImageView imageView;
        FrameLayout youTubeVideo;

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is not what you want to do. This is going to try to replace a fragment *every time a view is bound* to the list. If you truly need it, pass it into the constructor. Otherwise, just let the Activity or Fragment handle that logic in an OnItemClickListener.

Comment: I have the same problem, you was solved ?